# как мне увидеть на примере это кода как это работает. Я запускаю, но пустая страница выходит

Tags: php

Листинг 23.13. Статические страницы. Файл pages/StaticPage.php

```
<?php ## Статические страницы
  require_once "Cached.php";
  class StaticPage extends Cached
  {
    // Конструктор класса
    public function __construct($id)
    {
      // Проверяем нет ли такой страницы в кэше
      if ($this->isCached($this->id($id))) {
        // Есть, инициализируем объект содержимым кэша
        parent::__construct($this->title(), $this->content());
      } else {
        // Данные пока не кэшированы, извлекаем
        // содержимое из базы данных
         $query = "SELECT * FROM static_pages WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
         $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
         $sth = $dbh->execute($query, [$id]);
         $page = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         parent::__construct($page['title'], $page['title']);
        parent::__construct("Контакты", "Содержимое страницы Контакты");
      }
    }

    // Уникальный ключ для кэша
    public function id($name)
    {
      return "static_page_{$name}";
    }
  }
?>
```

Листинг 23.12. Базовый класс для кэшируемых страниц. Файл pages/Cached.php

```
<?php ## Базовый класс для кэшируемых страниц
  require_once "Page.php";
  class Cached extends Page
  {
    // Время действия кэша
    protected $expires;
    // Хранилище
    protected $store;

    // Конструктор класса
    public function __construct($title = '', $content = '', $expires = 0)
    {
      // Вызываем конструктор базового класса Page
      parent::__construct($title, $content);
      // Устанавливаем время жизни кэша
      $this->expires = $expires;
      // Подготовка хранилища
      // $this->store = new Memcached();
      // $this->store->addServer('localhost', 11211);
      // Размещение данных в хранилище
      $this->set($this->id('title'), $title);
      $this->set($this->id('content'), $content);
    }

    // Проверить есть ли позиция $key в кэше
    protected function isCached($key)
    {
      // return (bool) $this->store->get($key);
    }
    // Поместить в кэш по ключу $key значение $value
    // В случае если ключ уже существует:
    // 1. Не делать ничего, если $force принимает значение false
    // 2. Переписать, если $force принимает значение true
    protected function set($key, $value, $force = false)
    {
      // if ($force) {
      //   $this->store->set($key, $value, $this->expires);
      // } else {
      //   if($this->isCached($key)) {
      //     $this->store->set($key, $value, $this->expires);
      //   }
      // }
    }
    // Извлечение значения $key из кэша
    protected function get($key)
    {
      // return $this->store->get($key);
    }

    // Формируем уникальный ключ для хранилища
    public function id($name)
    {
      die("Что здесь делать? Неизвестно!");
    }

    // Получение заголовка страницы
    public final function title()
    {
      // if ($this->isCached($this->id('title'))) {
      //   return $this->get($this->id('title'));
      // } else {
         return parent::title();
      // }
    }
    // Получение содержимое страницы
    public final function content()
    {
      // if ($this->isCached($this->id('content'))) {
      //   return $this->get($this->id('content'));
      // } else {
         return parent::content();
      // }
    }
  }
?>
```

Page.php

```
<?php ## Базовый класс страницы
  class Page
  {
    // Любая страница имеет заголовок
    protected $title;
    // И содержимое
    protected $content;
    // Конструктор класса
    public function __construct($title = '', $content = '')
    {
      $this->title = $title;
      $this->content = $content;
    }
    // Получение заголовка страницы
    public function title()
    {
      return $this->title;
    }
    // Получение содержимого страницы
    public function content()
    {
      return $this->content;
    }
    // Формирование HTML-представления страницы
    public function render()
    {
      echo "<h1>".htmlspecialchars($this->title())."</h1>";
      echo "</p>".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($this->content()))."</p>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100283/discussion-on-question-by-php----------).

Comment: Это называется я тебе дал код, работай б..)))  Короче особо не вникая чтобы "это" работало нужно как миниму База MySQL с соответствуищей таблицей и Memcached Server с соответствуищей структурой ключей)))))))

Comment: включить ошибки + вывести все логи в файлик с запросами. Команду на серваке не помню.

Answer (score 1):

Если страница пустая, значит ты не видишь ошибок, в начало каждого файла вставь эти функции, после этого увидишь ошибку и иле несколько и дальше нужно их решать каждую уже по факту

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// дальше остальной код
```